# remove numbers from full text index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

Is there any way to make SQL Server not full-text index numbers and currency values?

According to `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` the index has a very large number of unique values such as `$            123,456` and other numerical data all stored within a single `NVARCHAR` column. I am not interested in these numbers and would like the indexer to ignore them entirely.

Is there a way to tell a full text index to ignore numbers (possibly by a language setting)? Or is there any way to run a regular expression or CLR extension over the input text before being passed to the full text indexer? Or can fdhost be made to ignore numbers?